# How do I start all shell sessions in a directory other than $HOME?

Tags: bash, terminal, environment-variables

When I open my non-login shell in Ubuntu, my present working directory is `/home/user_name` (my `$HOME` environment variable), but I want to change this such that when I start my terminal I am in some other directory.

I have read that when I start my terminal in Ubuntu a `.bashrc` file is sourced. So I added

```
export HOME=/home/user_name/Documents
```

to my `.bashrc` file. Now, when I open my terminal I am still in `/home/user_name` directory.

How can I change this?

Comment: Does this help? http://askubuntu.com/a/75223/212231

Comment: It might also be worth considering not doing this. The design of UNIX wasn't handed down by the forefathers for nothing you know.

Answer (score 74):

First of all, remove that line from your `.bashrc`. The way to do this in not by playing with `$HOME`, that variable will always point to your home directory and you don't want to change that just so your shells start in a different place.

I'm sure there will be a more elegant way to do this but as a temporary workaround you can simply add this line to your `.bashrc`:

```
cd ~/Documents
```

Since that file is read every time you start a new non-login shell (open a new terminal), the `cd` command will be executed and your terminals will start at `~/Documents` as you desire.

Comment: Note that it will affect all the non-login interactive shells (and login ones if you source your bashrc from your bash_profile) _and_ the non-interactive ones started by sshd.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Are you sure? Usually there is a `[[ -z "$PS1" ]] && exit` guard at the top of the `.bashrc` which should prevent this for non-interactive sessions.

Comment: @queueoverflow usually? In what operating system? In which distribution? Not on Debian, SuSe or CentOS. In fact, I think I've only ever seen that on Ubuntu.

Comment: @terdon I have seen it on Ubuntu and thought that was the general case.

Comment: This changes the behavior when opening a new tab. By default, a new tab is opened in the same directory as the current tab. With this command, a new tab is opened in `~/Documents`.

Comment: @JonathanScholbach yes, of course. A new tab is a new shell session. I have no idea what operating system or terminal emulator you are using, there is no "default" here since most terminals don't have tabs, but that's what would be the expected behavior. If you don't want that, you shouldn't configure your shell to move to a new directory as this answer describes.

Comment: @terdon: Thanks for your response! I use Ubuntu and bash. Do you know how I could start a new terminal session in my custom folder, but stay in the current directory when I open a new tab? (I don't want to change my root dir in /etc/passwd for this). I can open a new question for this as well, if this is preferred.

Comment: @JonathanScholbach yes, please open a new question but make sure to explain why you want this since a tab is the same as a new terminal. Also make sure to mention what terminal program you use.

Comment: @terdon: Do you think, I should ask this here, or on askubuntu?

Comment: @JonathanScholbach up to you, it is completely on topic on both sites.

Comment: @terdon Thanks again, your comments already helped me asking a better question. It is here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/736983/change-default-directory-in-gnome-bash-terminal

Answer (score 33):

The terminal will start in the working directory it inherits from its parent.

However, some allow to override it via configuration settings.

With `gnome-terminal`, you can edit your profile, tick *run a custom command instead of my shell* and make it:

```
sh -c 'cd ~/Documents; exec "${SHELL:-sh}"'
```

Answer (score 10):

Here's what I put in my `~/.bash_profile`:

```
alias curDir="pwd | sed -e 's/ /\\ /'"
alias save='echo `curDir` > ~/.saved_dir'
alias saved='cd `cat ~/.saved_dir`'
saved
```

and I rely on this all the time. Basically, when I'm working on some project, I'll `save` a main directory for it and then every subsequent session starts there. Then when I change projects or whatever, I'll just `save` somewhere else.

I found this question when looking for a better way, but what I've got is preferable to me than hardcoding one particular directory.

Comment: This works well in git bash as well. Just remember to restart the bash shell or use (I think) "source ~/.bash_profile" after changing the file.

Comment: @amos Why not use a soft link? It seems like a more canonical way to do what you're doing. Either way, this is a nice idea.

Comment: Just came across this, very simple but yet such a nice feature to have. Using it right now. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

For those that are looking at where the `.bashrc` file is, generally it is a hidden file in home directory.

#### To find it:

Open your terminal and go to the home directory, and then:

```
ls -al
```

to show the all hidden files. Now you will be able to see your `.bashrc` file.

#### In order to change default directory

1. Open `.bashrc` file in your text editor by entering the command:

   ```
   gedit .bashrc
   ```
2. Edit this file by adding your command in last, like:

   ```
   cd ~/YourDirectoryName
   ```
3. Save the file and restart the terminal.

Comment: The question doesn't ask *how* to edit .bashrc, he's already done it. And your answer is just a repeat of @terdon's answer from two years earlier.

Comment: I agree with @DavorCubranic , Shivam. You should rather transform your answer into a comment, I would say.

Answer (score -1):

Think about modifying `/etc/passwd` and change your default home directory

Comment: welcome to U&L OP want a temporary change.